# Is there a way to check if discord bot joins a server?

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I want to check if it joins a server so I can set prefixes, send messages etc.
I tried searching for this but I didn't find anything that could help.

I thought it could be an event so tried something like:

```js
client.on('join_guild', (guild) => {
    prefix = "!"
});
```

But, of course, it didn't work.

Is there something like the code shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [guildCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event. It gets triggered once your bot joins a new guild. Example code:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
    // This event triggers when the bot joins a guild.    
    console.log(`Joined new guild: ${guild.name}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, thats what i was searching for.